# Implementing infinite scroll, how to query data

Tags: php, mysql

This is the simplest title I came up with. *(because I am not that good in english)*

Anyway, here is the thing, I needing to know:

When you login to `facebook`, and then you continuously scroll down your homepage, it will come to the point where it will load for a few seconds and then results will show up again.

Facebook does not use `pagination` type, like `ebay or youtube does`. So how can I do what `facebook` does ?

Currently, I only do is `search` all results and `display` all of them. What I am thinking is, **what if the `search` is hundred to thousand records and then I will display all of them, then it might cause some problems.**

If you do not understand my english feel free to comment here. I need it so badly. BTW, I searched on some trusted other sites, I only know is to use `Limit` but I do not know how to **increase** the `Limit` if the user is on the last result of the current `Limit`.

example:

first, `Limit` is 500,
then when user is on the 500th result,
the `Limit` will increase or will add +500 to it's `Limit`,
then the user will continue the scroll down and so on.

*Feel free to comment if the title is lacking, too broad or does not match the description*

**Added question:**

for example I have 1000 records of image and some info in the image and then I `foreach` all of them.

What are the causes I will receive?

Comment: This is called lazy-loading, endless scroll or endless page.  See http://jscroll.com/ .

Comment: can this be done with no-javascript? @ForguesR

Comment: @upvote No, it can't.

Comment: i think pagination is suited for me as of now. thank you @Brad

Answer (score 1):

Infinite scroll, from a technical perspective, isn't much different than pagination.

The **data** is still paginated.  It's just **presented** in a way where the next page (of data) is loaded as the user scrolls, rather than clicking to the next page.

> what if the search is hundred to thousand records and then I will display all of them, then it might cause some problems.

It depends on what you're doing, but a thousand records really isn't that much data.

From the UX perspective, pagination is a generally a bad idea.  It adds an artificial point where folks have to wait to see other data in a completely different place, meaning they cannot visually compare information.  I suspect that sites like eBay are still doing this so that they can log another set of ad impressions.

On the other hand, infinite scroll isn't good for UX either.  The user is often surprised when they scroll to the bottom of a page, just to find that there is more to scroll to.

If you only have a thousand records to show, I'd just show them all at once.

Comment: my records can increase from hundreds to a hundred thousand or more. But for now what can you advise to me? So far I am developing my website, so the hundred thousand record is not important. What can you advise to me to do? Do a pagination, or just show them all at once and when the time that my records reach a thousand, I update my site to do a pagination ? What do you think ?

Comment: Oh, I am doing like what eBay does(ideally), display a list of pictures then some description of it.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single thing eBay does that I would suggest, as far as web design, usability, and front-end implementation goes.  Infinite scroll will probably suit you well, but you can always change it later.  It's an easy change.